# Multiplication of determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Show that for any vectors $\bf{a}$,$\bf{b}$,$\bf{c}$,$\bf{u}$,$\bf{v}$,$\bf{w}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$,

$$[\bf{a},\bf{b},\bf{c}][\bf{u},\bf{v},\bf{w}]=\begin{vmatrix}\bf{a}\cdot\bf{u}&\bf{a}\cdot\bf{v}&\bf{a}\cdot\bf{w}\\
\bf{b}\cdot\bf{u}&\bf{b}\cdot\bf{v}&\bf{b}\cdot\bf{w}\\
\bf{c}\cdot\bf{u}&\bf{c}\cdot\bf{v}&\bf{c}\cdot\bf{w}\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

My question: is there a more elegant way to prove that without actually delving into tedious direct approach by definition?

I was considering that "summing" approach, using the fact that

$$[\textbf{a},\textbf{b},\textbf{c}][\textbf{u},\textbf{v},\textbf{w}]=\bigg(\sum^3_{i,j,k=1}\epsilon_{ijk}a_ib_jc_k\bigg)\bigg(\sum^3_{i,j,k=1}\epsilon_{ijk}u_iv_jw_k\bigg)$$

But I am very weak with manipulations of sums and can't get much further. Any hints?

**Note** This problem occured when the text book formalized the corkscrew rule and discussed orientation of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, meaning even matrices has not been introduced yet, as the chapter itself was analyzing vectors in the given space.

Comment: have you seen http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177560/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that if $\bf{a},\bf{b},\bf{c}$ are not linearly independent,
then both sides are zero and we are done.

So we may assume that $(\bf{a},\bf{b},\bf{c})$ is a basis of ${\mathbb R}^3$. For the same reason we may further assume that $(\bf{u},\bf{v},\bf{w})$ is a basis of ${\mathbb R}^3$.Say that a sextuple of vectors $(\bf{a},\bf{b},\bf{c},\bf{u},\bf{v},\bf{w})$ is $\bf good$ if the desired equality holds.

Note that if we multiply one of the vectors in the sextuplet by a constant $\lambda$, then both sides of the equality are multiplied by $\lambda$, so this transformation does not affect goodness.

Similarly, if we make interchange $a$ and $b$, or interchange $u$ and $v$ (but do not
mix up any of $a,b,c$ with any of $u,v,w$), then both sides of the equality are unchanged,
so this transformation does not affect goodness.

Also, if we replace $b$ with $b+a$, or replace $v$ with $v+u$ (but do not
mix up any of $a,b,c$ with any of $u,v,w$), then both sides of the equality are unchanged,
so this transformation does not affect goodness.

Now it is well-known that iterating those transformations allows us to go from
the canonical  basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ of ${\mathbb R}^3$ to any basis, and vice versa (those transformations are all revertible); this is the Gauss method to solve linear systems.

So we can assume without loss of generality that both $(\bf{a},\bf{b},\bf{c})$ and
$(\bf{u},\bf{v},\bf{w})$ are in fact the canonical basis, in which case both sides 
of the equality are clearly equal to $1$. This concludes the (computation-free) proof.

Comment: thank you! your answer will be rewarded, once I am able to do that :)