# Prove $|A.B|=|A|.|B|$ using matrix algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

How to prove that the determinant of the product of matrices is equal to product of their respective determinants ?.ie,

> $$
> |A.B|=|A|.|B|
> $$
>   where $A,B$ are square matrices of the same order.

I have no clue of where to start, I just know the following 
$$
|A|I=A(adj A)=(adj A)A
$$
**Note:** I have checked a similar problem at [Proving determinant product rule combinatorially](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177560/proving-determinant-product-rule-combinatorially) which gives a combinatorial proof of the statement which is kinda cumbersome by the use of Combinatorics in a matrix problem. So I hope its worth asking for an alternative proof using only the properties of matrices.

Comment: Usually one proves that any matrix can be written as a product of elementary matrices and then one shows that determinants are multiplicative on elementary matrices.

Comment: If you want a rigorous proof of this, there are unfortunately no real shortcuts you can take. You can find a proof here with all the details: http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-PDM.html

Comment: Another approach is to define a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to\mathbb{R}:X\to \det(AX)/\det(A)$ and show that this function has the property of being multilinear, alternating and maps the identity matrix to 1. It can be shown that the determinant function is the only map with these properties, thus $\det(X)=\det(AX)/\det(A)$.

Comment: @HansLundmark thanx for mentioning it. But i am looking for proofs only using properties of matrices. Hope its worth asking considering the combinatorial proof you mentioned is not an easy one.

Comment: It's o.k. not proving this in class. But deferring the proof (which is in all textbooks) to the exercises is cheating.

Comment: @Mathematician42 thnx. could u pls comment on my attempted proof ?

Comment: thanks for the comments. could u pls clarify my attempt to prove it ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B\in \Re^{n\times n}$ be two $n\times n$ matrices.

Now we can distinguish between 2 cases:

**Case 1:** $A$ isn't invertible. Therefore the product $AB$ won't be invertible either. In this case, $|AB|=|A|\cdot|B|=0$ holds true (both sides are equal to $0$).

**Case 2:** $A$ *is* invertible. In this case, both $A$ and the Identity Matrix $I_n$ are equivalent by rows: $$A=E_p\cdot E_{p-1}\ldots E_1\cdot I_n=E_p\cdot E_{p-1}\ldots E_1$$

And therefore: $$\begin{align*} |AB| &= |E_p\cdot E_{p-1}\ldots E_1\cdot B| \\
&=|E_p|\cdot|E_{p-1}\ldots E_1\cdot B| \\ &= |E_p|\cdot|E_{p-1}|\cdot |\ldots E_1\cdot B| \\ &=\ldots \\ &= |E_p\ldots E_1|\cdot |B| \\ &= |A|\cdot|B|\end{align*}$$

Comment: How do you show that $A$ singular implies $|A|=0$?

Comment: That's by definition, if I'm not wrong. $A$ is singular iif $|A|=0$ and vice versa

Comment: The usual defiition is "not invertible" - in any case, above you use the fact that if $A$ is not invertible then $|A|=0$. How do you prove _that_?

Answer (score 1):

Notations like $\sum_j$ or $\prod_k$ will always mean $\sum_{j=1}^n$ and $\prod_{k=1}^n$; there's  going to be enough typing here even with that convention.

If $\sigma\in S_n$ define $|\sigma|=1$ if $\sigma$ is even,  $-1$ if $\sigma$ is odd. The simplest definition of the determinant is
$$|A|=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}|\sigma|\prod_ja_{j,\sigma(j)}.$$

Ok, maybe that doesn't *look* as simple as various other definitions, but it's often the simplest to use in proving things about determinants; if whatever formula is true it *must* follow by just plugging in and working it out. We're going to use this to show the determinant is multiplicative - the proof is "simple" in that it uses absolutely no previous results, nothing but the fact that multiplication distributes over addition.

In general what is the product of a bunch of sums, $\prod_j\sum_k\alpha_{jk}$? It's the sum of products, each product being the product of one term from the first sum times one term from the second sum, etc. That is, if we let $X$ be the set of all functions from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to itself, in general we have $$\prod_j\sum_k\alpha_{jk}
=\sum_{\psi\in X}\prod_j\alpha_{j,\psi(j)}.$$

We extend the notation $|\sigma|$ to $X$ by saying $|\sigma|=0$ if $\sigma\in X\setminus S_n$. Note that if $\sigma,\psi\in X$ and $\sigma\psi\in S_n$ then $\sigma$ must be surjective and $\psi$ must be injective, so in fact $\sigma,\psi\in S_n$. Hence $$|\sigma\psi|=|\sigma|\,|\psi|\quad(\sigma,\psi\in X).$$

Now say $AB=C$. In the obvious notation this says$$c_{jk}=\sum_ia_{ji}b_{ik}.$$So if $\sigma\in S_n$ then$$
\sum_jc_{j,\sigma(j)}=\sum_{\psi\in X}\prod_ja_{j,\psi(j)}b_{\psi(j),\sigma(j)}.$$

Hence $$|AB|=\sum_{\psi\in X}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}|\sigma|\prod_ja_{j,\psi(j)}b_{\psi(j),\sigma(j)}.$$

Now note that since $|\psi|=0$ for $\psi\in X\setminus S_n$ we have $$|A|=\sum_{\psi\in X}|\psi|\prod_ja_{j,\psi(j)}.$$Multiplying this by the original definitoin of $|B|$ gives $$|A|\,|B|=\sum_{\psi\in X}\sum_{\phi\in S_n}|\sigma\psi|\prod_ja_{j,\psi((j)}b_{j,\sigma(j)}.$$

Since for every $\psi\in X$ either $|\psi\sigma|=0$ or $\psi$ is a permutation of $\{1,2\dots,n\}$ that last is equal to $$\sum_{\psi\in X}\sum_{\phi\in S_n}|\sigma\psi|\prod_ja_{j,\psi((j)}b_{\psi(j),\sigma(\psi(j))}.$$

And again, since if $|\psi|\ne0$ then $\sigma\mapsto\sigma\psi$ is a bijection on $S_n$, that last expression is equal to $$\sum_{\psi\in X}\sum_{\phi\in S_n}|\sigma|\prod_ja_{j,\psi((j)}b_{\psi(j),\sigma(j)},$$which is $|AB|$.

Comment: This is an unappropiate answer in my opinion. The OP said he has basic knowledge in combinatorics. He won't be able to understand a single line of math you wrote, with all due respect. Let's make maths simple and fun.

Comment: And I meant no disrespect by the way! I admire how much maths you know, for sure. But most of us, including OP, have limited knowledge and I'm sure this answer won't be any useful to him. You should seriously consider writing a book on advanced maths, though ;)

Comment: There's no law saying answers have to be solely for the benefit of the OP. This _is_ a complete self-contained proof - the other answers so far all assume various preliminary not-quite-trivial things about determinants.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thnx. But a combinatorial proof is asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177560/proving-determinant-product-rule-combinatorially. I was looking for an alternative proof constrained to matrix algebra as much as possible. It'd be helpful if you could rather mention the drawbacks in other answer.

Comment: @ss1729 Sorry, I had no idea that the proof above was "combinatorial".

Answer (score 0):

Thanx @ZeroXLR for the hint.

> $$
> |A.B|=|A|.|B|
> $$

$\color{blue}{\text{Theorem 1}}:$ Suppose that $A$ is a square matrix of size $n$ and $E$ is any elementary matrix of size $n$, then
$$\boxed{
|E.A|=|E|.|A|}
$$

Proof :

**1.)** $A=[a_{i,j}]$ and $B=E_l(k).A=[b_{i,j}]$ where $b_{l,j}=k.a_{l,j}$

$$
|E_l(k).A|=|B|=\sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{l+j}.b_{l,j}.|b(l\ |\ j)|\\
=\sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{l+j}.b_{l,j}.|a(l\ |\ j)|\\
=\sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{l+j}.k.a_{l,j}.|a(l\ |\ j)|\\
=k.\sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{l+j}.a_{l,j}.|a(l\ |\ j)|\\
\color{red}{|E_l(k).A|=k.|A|=|E_l(k)|.|A|}
$$
**2.)** Swapping of adjascent rows, $A=[a_{i,j}]$ and $B=E_{l,l+1}.A=[b_{i,j}]$ where $a_{l,j}=b_{l+1,j}$ and $a_{l+1,j}=b_{l,j}$
$$
|E_{l,l+1}.A|=|B|=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{l+1+j}.b_{l+1,j}.|b(l+1\ |\ j)|\\
=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{l+j}.(-1)^1.a_{l,j}.|a(m\ |\ j)|\\
=(-1).\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{l+j}.a_{l,j}.|a(m\ |\ j)|\\
\color{red}{|E_{l,l+1}.A|=-|A|=|E_{l,l+1}|.|A|}
$$

**3.)** $A=[a_{i,j}]$ and $B=E_{l,m}(k).A=[b_{i,j}]$ where $b_{m,j}=a_{m,j}+k.a_{l,j}$
$$
|E_{l,m}(k).A|=|B|=\sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{m+j}.b_{m,j}.|b(m\ |\ j)|\\
=\sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{m+j}.(a_{m,j}+k.a_{l,j}).|a(m\ |\ j)|\\
=\sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{m+j}.a_{m,j}.|a(m\ |\ j)|+k.\sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{m+j}.a_{l,j}.|a(m\ |\ j)|=|A|+0\\
\color{red}{|E_{l,m}(k).A|=|A|=|E_{l,m}(k).A|.|A|}
$$

$\color{blue}{\text{Theorem 2}}:$ For the three possible elementary matrix we have the determinants,
$$
\boxed{|E_{i,j}|=-1\\
|E_i{(k)}|=k\\
|E_{i,j}(k)|=1}
$$
Proof :

Using $\color{blue}{\text{Theorem 1}}$,

$$
|E_{i,j}|=|E_{i,j}.I|=-|I|=-1\\
|E_i(k)|=|E_i(k).I|=k|I|=k.1=k\\
|E_{i,j}(k)|=|E_{i,j}(k).I|=|I|=1
$$

$\color{blue}{\text{Theorem 3}}:$ If $A$ is a nonsingular matrix, then there exists elementary matrices $E_1,E_2,E_3....E_n$ so that,

$$\boxed{
A=E_n....E_3.E_2.E_1.I=E_n....E_3.E_2.E_1}
$$

$\color{blue}{\text{Theorem 4}}:$

A matrix $A$ is called singular if the equation $Ax=0$ has a nonzero solution.

Proof :

If $A$ is non-singular, ie. $|A|\neq0$,
$$
Ax=b\implies A^{-1}\big(Ax\big)=A^{-1}b \quad (A \text{ is non-singular}\implies A\text{ is invertible})
\\Ix=A^{-1}b\implies x=A^{-1}b
$$
Thus,
$$
Ax=0\implies x=0
$$
If $A$ is non-singular $Ax=0$ can have only the trivial solution $x=0$. Thus,
$$\boxed{
Ax=0 \text{ has non-trivial solution}\iff |A|=0  \text{ }\big(\text{i.e, }A\text{ is singular}\big)}
$$

**Case 1 :** If $B$ is singular,

From $\color{blue}{\text{Theorem 4}}$,

there is a vector $x\neq 0$ such that $Bx=0$. Hence,
$$
ABx=A(Bx)=A.0=0
$$
The equation $ABx=0$ also has a nontrivial solution $x\neq0$. Hence, $AB$ is singular ie. $|AB|=0$
$$
|AB|=0=|A||B|
$$

**Case 2 :** If $B$ is non-singular,

$$
|AB|=|A.E_n....E_3.E_2.E_1|\qquad\color{blue}{\big(\text{Theorem 3}\big)}
\\=|A|.|E_n|....|E_3|.|E_2|.|E_1|\qquad\color{blue}{\big(\text{Theorem 1}\big)}
\\=|A|.|E_n....E_3.E_2.E_1|\qquad\color{blue}{\big(\text{Theorem 1}\big)}
\\=|A|.|B|\qquad\color{blue}{\big(\text{Theorem 3}\big)}\qquad\color{white}{\big(\text{There.}\big)}
$$

Comment: How do you show that $A$ singular implies $|A|=0$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thanx for mentioning it. I have edited the answer. pls check.

Comment: Your answer is a much larger version than mine, but it essentially says the same thing ;)

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question at all. "Theorem 4" is more  a definition than a theorem, and then in the proof you seem to be just assuming what I asked about.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich srry i dont understand ur point. $A$ is singular means $|A|=0$ right ?. Thats wht we really mean by saying a matrix is singular. What u mean by "show that $A$ singular implies $|A|=0$" ?

Comment: No, $A$ singular means $A$ is not invertible. So  nonsingular means invertible - Theorem 3 is a standard fact about invertible matricies. _If_ your definition of singular is $|A|=0$ then all through this you use facts aobut determinants without proof.

Comment: For example, with "my" definitions, Theorem 3 says an invertible matrix is a product of elementary matrices - fine, that's proved earlly in the course. If you define singular the way you say _then_ theorem  3 says that if $|A|\ne0$ then $A$ is a product of elementary matrices - how do you prove _that_?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $A^{-1}=\frac{adj A}{|A|}$. So if a matrix is invertible $|A|\neq 0$, ie. non-singular. When $|A|=0$ it does not have an inverse, ie. singular. So the conditions comes directly from the equation for $A^{-1}$ right. So whats the big deal in proving it. I think i can just mean $|A|=0$ when i say "singular"

Comment: You are using facts before having proved those facts, i.e. this is a circular reasoning. David C. Ullrich's concern is justified and a problem I also have when reading your version. Perhaps it is useful to state your definition of a determinant as well. Personally, I would define a determinant map by it's properties (thus as an alternating multilinear map). From these properties one can easily deduce certain facts (i.e. multiplicativity, relation with singularity, ...) and find a general formula which David uses as the definition. Moreover, this proves uniqueness of determinants as well.

Comment: @Mathematician42 thanks. I have edited my original answer. Could u pls check and be more specific. Is it now a decent well defined proof ? (assuming you were talking about theorem 1 and 2)

Comment: You're still using all sorts of facts about determinants without proof. For example, at one point you use the fact that you get the same answer if you "expand" along any row. How do you prove _that_? (Yes, these are all well known facts. So? If you want to _prove_ something you have to prove them - if simply citing well-known facts is enough then we don't need to prove $|AB|=|A|\,|B|$ in the first place - it's well known...)

Comment: And a big one: How do you prove that $A^{-1}=\adj(A)/|A|$?

Comment: ALso btw you _use_ theorem 2 in the proof of Theorem 1, then you prove Theorem 2 using Theorem 1.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich i think u have a point. The above proof uses properties of determinants as well known facts. So i guess i agree that it is not a self contained proof. But for someone who is not an expert i think its ok to try to prove $|AB|=|A||B|$ from other facts about matrices and determinants.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Where do i uses theorem 2 in the proof of theorem 1 ?. For example, $B=E_l(k)A\implies b_{lj}=ka_{lj}$(which is try from the definition of $E_l(k)$). If I am finding determinant along the row at which $E_l(k)$ operates, $|E_l(k)A|=|B|=\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{l+j}b_{lj}|b(l\ |\ j)|=\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{l+j}ka_{lj}|a(l\ |\ j)|=k\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{l+j}a_{lj}|a(l\ |\ j)|=k|A|$. Where do I use theorem 2 ?

Comment: In the proof of Theorem 1 you "prove" that, for example, if $B=E_l(k)A$ then  $|B|=k|A|$. Of course you don't actually _prove_  that, since  you;re  using unproved  facts about determinants. But now after you "prove" that $|B|=k|A|$ you conclude that $|B|=|E_j(k)||A|$. Which is using $|E_l(k)|=k$, precisely what Theorem  2 says.

Comment: "But for someone who is not an expert i think its ok to try to prove $|AB|=|A||B|$ from other facts about matrices and determinants. " Fine, but if you want a simple proof you get the simplest possible proof by using the fact that $|AB|=|A|\,|B|$. A person _can_  give an  actual _proof_ using factorization into elementary matricies, but that requires firsts proving  the various preliminary results. At some  point there's going  to be some of what you call "combinatorics" if you think you're giving a proof without "combinatorics" you're just fooling  yourself by omitting steps.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich i think i am only using the fact that determinant can be found using the expansion $|A|=\sum_j(-1)^{l+j}a_{lj}|a(l|j)|$. Then $|E_l(k)A|=k|A|$ from theorem 1 and using that $|E_l(k)|=|E_l(k)I|=k|I|=k$. Now using both $|E_l(k)A|=k|A|=|E_l(k)||A|$